# $location.search() re-runs controller all the time

Tags: angularjs

I have a search page with several inputs in a form in angularjs. I would like to use the `$location.search()` api to "store" the search input values into the URL so that upon a "back" button event, it will reload the search result. While the `$location.search()` api method works out find by modifying the URL with my search parameters embedded, it always wants to re-run the controller whenever that is called. This kind of screws up my controller initialization logic. Is there a way to tell `$location.search()` not to re-run controller whenever it's called?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting `reloadOnSearch` to `false` for that particular route in your [route provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)

Comment: @Niner I'm glad it was it. By the way no need to thanks in comments ;) accept and upvote is just fine: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment